# Two different steps of algorithm with differing complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm that proceeds thus:

```
Step 1: Do process A to produce outputs P_1, P_2, ..., P_K

Step 2: For each output of Step 1, P_k, solve process B.
```

`K` is `O(n^2)`. So, process `B` needs to run `O(n^2)` times. Step 1, itself, however, takes `O(n^4)` time.

The worst-case time it takes for process `B` to operate on `P_k` is not a knwon function of `n`. The time as a function of `n` is actually an open research question.

So, what is the right way to denote the complexity of this algorithm?

Is it `O(max(n^4, n^2 T))` where `T` is the maximum time (yet unknown) it takes to solve `P_k`?

Comment: If `T` describes the complexity of solving for all `P_i`, I would denote it as `O(n^4 + T(n^2))`.

Comment: You don't know anything about the complexity of this algorithm.  Since you only have upper bounds, it could be very fast.  Since `B` could take forever, it could be very slow.

Comment: When you say "the worst-case time it takes for process B to operate on P_k is not a known function of n", what is n? Is n the same n that was the size of the input to process A? or do you mean "the worst case time of B on input x is not known as a function of x?"